# Remember submitted field in form drop down list

Tags: php, forms

I have a HTML form and PHP script on the same page, which calculates a price based in the input from the HTML form.

It is important that the information provided in the form is stored when the PHP script runs, so that the customer can see what the price is based on.

The following code stores the text input:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="420" name="stofprijs" width="100" placeholder="Prijs"  value="<?=( isset( $_POST['stofprijs'] ) ? $_POST['stofprijs'] : '' )?>"> euro.
```

I had tried to store the data from the drop down list with this code:

On top:

```
<?php
    $gordijnsoort = $_POST['gordijnsoort'];
?>
```

In the form:

```
<select name="gordijnsoort">
    <option value="gordijn" <?php echo $gordijnsoort == 'gordijn' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Gordijn</option>
    <option value="vouwgordijn" <?php echo $gordijnsoort == 'vouwgordijn' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Vouwgordijn</option>
    <option value="ringgordijn" <?php echo $gordijnsoort == 'ringgordijn' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Ringgordijn</option>
</select>
```

The data is stored, but the empty form keeps displaying the error:

`Undefined index: gordijnsoort`

The form should only save the variable when the customer submits the form, but now it's already looking for the variable at the start.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $gordijnsoort = array_key_exists('gordijnsoort', $_POST) ? $_POST['gordijnsoort'] : "";
?>
```

You will receive the error because at first call the `$_POST` array is empty and you try to access a undefined key.

Comment: This works perfectly and solved my problem. If I read it correctly, the 'array_key_exists('gordijnsoort', $_POST) ?' checks if there is any data submitted?

Comment: Indirectly it does. It checks if the array has the specified string as a key. If no data is submitted the key is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `$_POST` is empty. It will only be filled after you submit your form. So first you have to check with `isset`, `empty`  if `gordijnsoort` exists.

E.g.

```
$gordijnsoort = isset($_POST['gordijnsoort']) ? $_POST['gordijnsoort'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your variable to NULL if it doesn't exist.

```
$gordijnsoort = isset($_POST['gordijnsoort']) ? $_POST['gordijnsoort'] : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to check if `$_POST['gordijnsoort']` isset. Your code should look like:

```
$gordijnsoort = "";
if(isset($_POST['gordijnsoort'])
    $gordijnsoort = $_POST['gordijnsoort'];
```

This will prevent callign non existing index before sending the form.